# How do you verify GCM client is able to receive messages correctly?

Tags: android, push-notification, registration, google-cloud-messaging, messaging

Question regarding implementing GCM  client/server :

1 Register Client on GCM and received registration ID : success
2 Send message from Server to client Registration ID : success
3 Receive message on Client :  Not received,  no notification.

What is a good way to debug #3 above?   Is there a method to ensure that Server has sent message successfully to GCM with the specified RegistrationID ?

Here is the Manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--
  - Copyright 2013 Google Inc.
  -
  - Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License"); you may not
  - use this file except in compliance with the License. You may obtain a copy
  - of the License at
  -
  - http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
  -
  - Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
  - distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS, WITHOUT
  - WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied. See the
  - License for the specific language governing permissions and limitations
  - under the License.
-->
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.google.android.gcm.demo.app" android:versionCode="1" android:versionName="1.0">

    <!-- GCM requires Android SDK version 2.2 (API level 8) or above. -->
    <!-- The targetSdkVersion is optional, but it's always a good practice
         to target higher versions. -->
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" android:targetSdkVersion="16"/>

    <!-- GCM connects to Google Services. -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <!-- GCM requires a Google account. -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />

    <!-- Keeps the processor from sleeping when a message is received. -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />

    <!--
     Creates a custom permission so only this app can receive its messages.

     NOTE: the permission *must* be called PACKAGE.permission.C2D_MESSAGE,
           where PACKAGE is the application's package name.
    -->
    <permission android:name="com.google.android.gcm.demo.app.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.gcm.demo.app.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />

    <!-- This app has permission to register and receive data message. -->
    <uses-permission
        android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />

    <!-- Main activity. -->
    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <activity
            android:name=".DemoActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
                android:launchMode="singleTop">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <!--
          WakefulBroadcastReceiver that will receive intents from GCM
          services and hand them to the custom IntentService.

          The com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND permission is necessary
          so only GCM services can send data messages for the app.
        -->
        <receiver
            android:name=".GcmBroadcastReceiver"
            android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
            <intent-filter>
                <!-- Receives the actual messages. -->
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
                <category android:name="com.google.android.gcm.demo.app" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
        <service android:name=".GcmIntentService" />
    </application>

</manifest>



Here is the BroadCastReceiver: 

/*
 * Copyright 2013 Google Inc.
 *
 * Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
 * you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
 * You may obtain a copy of the License at
 *
 *   http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
 *
 * Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
 * distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
 * WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
 * See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
 * limitations under the License.
 */
package com.google.android.gcm.demo.app;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.ComponentName;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v4.content.WakefulBroadcastReceiver;


/**
 * This {@code WakefulBroadcastReceiver} takes care of creating and managing a
 * partial wake lock for your app. It passes off the work of processing the GCM
 * message to an {@code IntentService}, while ensuring that the device does not
 * go back to sleep in the transition. The {@code IntentService} calls
 * {@code GcmBroadcastReceiver.completeWakefulIntent()} when it is ready to
 * release the wake lock.
 */

public class GcmBroadcastReceiver extends WakefulBroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        // Explicitly specify that GcmIntentService will handle the intent.
        ComponentName comp = new ComponentName(context.getPackageName(),
                GcmIntentService.class.getName());
        // Start the service, keeping the device awake while it is launching.
        startWakefulService(context, (intent.setComponent(comp)));
        setResultCode(Activity.RESULT_OK);
    }
}


Here is the IntentService:



/*
 * Copyright (C) 2013 The Android Open Source Project
 *
 * Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
 * you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
 * You may obtain a copy of the License at
 *
 *      http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
 *
 * Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
 * distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
 * WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
 * See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
 * limitations under the License.
 */

package com.google.android.gcm.demo.app;

import com.google.android.gms.gcm.GoogleCloudMessaging;

import android.app.IntentService;
import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.SystemClock;
import android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat;
import android.util.Log;

/**
 * This {@code IntentService} does the actual handling of the GCM message.
 * {@code GcmBroadcastReceiver} (a {@code WakefulBroadcastReceiver}) holds a
 * partial wake lock for this service while the service does its work. When the
 * service is finished, it calls {@code completeWakefulIntent()} to release the
 * wake lock.
 */
public class GcmIntentService extends IntentService {
    public static final int NOTIFICATION_ID = 1;
    private NotificationManager mNotificationManager;
    NotificationCompat.Builder builder;

    public GcmIntentService() {
        super("GcmIntentService");
    }
    public static final String TAG = "GCM Demo";

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
        Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
        GoogleCloudMessaging gcm = GoogleCloudMessaging.getInstance(this);
        // The getMessageType() intent parameter must be the intent you received
        // in your BroadcastReceiver.
        String messageType = gcm.getMessageType(intent);

        if (!extras.isEmpty()) {  // has effect of unparcelling Bundle
            /*
             * Filter messages based on message type. Since it is likely that GCM will be
             * extended in the future with new message types, just ignore any message types you're
             * not interested in, or that you don't recognize.
             */
            if (GoogleCloudMessaging.MESSAGE_TYPE_SEND_ERROR.equals(messageType)) {
                sendNotification("Send error: " + extras.toString());
            } else if (GoogleCloudMessaging.MESSAGE_TYPE_DELETED.equals(messageType)) {
                sendNotification("Deleted messages on server: " + extras.toString());
            // If it's a regular GCM message, do some work.
            } else if (GoogleCloudMessaging.MESSAGE_TYPE_MESSAGE.equals(messageType)) {
                // This loop represents the service doing some work.
                for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
                    Log.i(TAG, "Working... " + (i + 1)
                            + "/5 @ " + SystemClock.elapsedRealtime());
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(5000);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    }
                }
                Log.i(TAG, "Completed work @ " + SystemClock.elapsedRealtime());
                // Post notification of received message.
                sendNotification("Received: " + extras.toString());
                Log.i(TAG, "Received: " + extras.toString());
            }
        }
        // Release the wake lock provided by the WakefulBroadcastReceiver.
        GcmBroadcastReceiver.completeWakefulIntent(intent);
    }

    // Put the message into a notification and post it.
    // This is just one simple example of what you might choose to do with
    // a GCM message.
    private void sendNotification(String msg) {
        mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager)
                this.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0,
                new Intent(this, DemoActivity.class), 0);

        NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =
                new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_stat_gcm)
        .setContentTitle("GCM Notification")
        .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle()
        .bigText(msg))
        .setContentText(msg);

        mBuilder.setContentIntent(contentIntent);
        mNotificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, mBuilder.build());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

GCM server returns a response to each HTTP request you send to it. The response tells you whether your message was rejected by Google for any reason (such as too long payload, invalid registration ID, missing registration ID, etc...). If you get a successful response from Google, that means GCM server accepted your message and there's nothing wrong with your server code.

Here's a sample response with some errors and some successful messages :

```
{ "multicast_id": 216,
  "success": 3,
  "failure": 3,
  "canonical_ids": 1,
  "results": [
    { "message_id": "1:0408" },
    { "error": "Unavailable" },
    { "error": "InvalidRegistration" },
    { "message_id": "1:1516" },
    { "message_id": "1:2342", "registration_id": "32" },
    { "error": "NotRegistered"}
  ]
}
```

Once you get a successful response you don't know for sure that the message was actually delivered to the device. There can be several reasons for the message not being delivered (the device being offline, the device being connected via WiFi to a network in which port 5228 is blocked, the device having recently uninstalled the app, etc...). Of course, the problem may be in the client (Android app) code.

Comment: Eran - yes,  the issue is client is not receiving notifications,  so it may be something in the client code.

Comment: @user3311838 If you have a problem with the client code, posting your manifest and broadcast receiver / intent service may help to get your problem solved.

Comment: Eran - please see Manifest / code in my Question update

Comment: @user3311838 The code looks fine. Do you get anything GCM related printed in the logcat?

Comment: Got an "Invalid Registration" error when server tries to send a MSG to client.     Is there a method to check if  a RegistrationID is valid prior to sending a MSG?

Comment: @user3311838 No there isn't. Are you sure you are using the exact registration ID you got in the client from Google? Perhaps you didn't store it correctly in the server.

Comment: Eran - here is a possible cause of error.   TestApp client UI displays the registration ID on UI, BUT, does not provide an easy way to capture the ID string.  Therefore I had to resort to manually copying the ID string character by character.

Comment: Eran - I have not stored the ID string in server by code yet. Here is what I'm doind now:   TestApp client UI displays the registration ID on UI, BUT does not provide an easy way to capture the ID string.   Therefore I had to resort to manually copying the ID string character by character, then hard-code this ID string as the targetID in Server->SendMsg () method. surely there could be error there.    I did review the ID string multiple times,  also used OCR on the image,  but it still did not work.   Looks like the ID string displayed may not be exactly the same as the actual string.

Comment: @user3311838 Why don't you run the app from eclipse (with your device connected to your PC) and copy the registration ID from the LogCat?

Comment: Eran - I tried with a different device and regID and  no longer get the invalid registration error.  The device is still unable to receive notifications..

Comment: Eran - How does GCM send messages to Client ?  via HTTP ?

Comment: Is there some setting on the device we need to enable / disable to receive notification ?

Comment: @user3311838 ports 5228-5230 (usually just 5228) are used by the device to connect to GCM when the internet connection is via WiFi. These ports must not be blocked in order for GCM to work for WiFi connections.

Comment: Eran - yes, we have checked and our Wifi router does not block 5288.      Also,  I realized the following dependency in build.gridle is missing :     dependencies {
  compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services:3.1.+"
}                                                               Caution: When you add the Play Services library to your project, be sure to add it with resources, as described in Setup Google Play Services SDK.

Comment: Eran - is this dependency a common cause of not being able to receive msg?

Comment: @user3311838 If your device managed to register to GCM (you got a registration ID), you don't have a problem with the play services library. I'm assuming you checked port 5228 and not 5288 as you wrote.